# Finding a non-euclidean geometry model - Howard Eves' Geometry

Tags: geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

I was given a set of axioms and the task to find two models.  found the first one without any real problem.  The second one is proving to be very difficult.  Thought I finally had it, but as you can see, my model 2 violates axiom 3.  Can anyone offer a hint on finding a valid model?

[image]

Comment: Are the green lines 4 different lines? Like, HAB, BCD, DEF, FGH? If so you are also violating A5. Either way, as a hint, try removing the green lines, but keep the blue, and try something different.

Comment: You are right, the curves are the lines you listed.  And I did them that way so A5 WOULD work.  For example, line AIE, and point G not on AIE.  G is on AHG, CIG, and EFG, all of which go through AIE.  So the curve gave me a line that G is on but not on AIE.  Then I noticed that HG are on two lines, AHG and HGF, violating A3.  I tried removing the green, and using other curves, tried without curves, I just don't see how 9 points in enough for 12 lines and keeping all 5 axioms.
But yeah, violated A5 as well, I didn't see that before.  Line HGF and point D  for example.

Comment: Try adding something like ADF.

Comment: What Josh said + definitely get rid of all the green lines.

Comment: Wow.    Looks messy, but... I think it works....  https://www.dropbox.com/s/l2lcl4e3q40aimn/Screen%20Shot%202017-07-14%20at%2010.35.10%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: Thanks!!  (this is the part of geometry I'm not so good at... the abstract part.  I'm more analytical)

Comment: One way to look at the $9$ point example is to take all ordered pairs of elements of $\mathbb Z_3$. Then the a line with the three distinct points $(x_i,y_i)$ ($i=1,2,3$) if and only if $x_1+x_2+x_3=0,y_1+y_2+y_3=0$.